# LibreOffice PDF exporting issue - transparent objects

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, openoffice.org

When I export my presentation to PDF the first slide, whose master slide has a white and transparent field turns black and transparent.

Anybody has an idea what is going on?

Comment: Can U add more info? version of libreoffice - presentation was made in libreoffice or first on office? take a look at this http://help.libreoffice.org/Impress/Changing_the_Slide_Background_Fill or check if it not a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/768508

Answer (score 3):

Do you export as PDF/A-1a? Make sure that the PDF/A-1a option is disabled when exporting to PDF, since [PDF/A-1a doesn't allow transparent objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A#Description):

[image: PDF Options]

BTW: This affects every kind of LIbreOffice / OpenOffice.org file exporing to PDF; Calc / Writer files may contain transparent content, too.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you could try to use **cups-pdf**.

[image: Install via the software center]

When installed (re)start LibreOffice, open your document, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select "PDF" as printer.

In "Settings" you can change the resolution if you want to; default are 300 DPI.

Click "Print" and you will find the PDF file in ~/PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The printing trick by @jakob worked for me one time, but not another, not sure why. Anyway, I found a better way [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=66631):

- Select the desired sections in the page you want printed
- Go to export, then select the `Selection` radio option, and export.
- Now this exported pdf can be used as a stamp.